# Convergence of equation in late time

Tags: convergence-divergence, partial-differential-equations, uniform-convergence

Suppose $$u_{t}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}$$ on the region $0\leq x,y \leq 1$ and that $u=0$ on the boundary.

Show that $$\int^1_0\int^1_0u^2dxdy\xrightarrow{}0, \text{ as } t\xrightarrow{}\infty $$

I'm really lost as to begin here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Decreasing and bounded below by 0 is not enough to conclude the result. For example $1+\frac{1}{t}$ is decreasing and bounded below by 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Poincare's Inequality,
$$ \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2\ge\lambda_1\|u\|_{L^2}^2. $$
Here $\lambda_1>0$ is the first eigenvalue of $-\Delta$. Multiplying both sides of the equation by $u$ and integrating in $\Omega$, one has
$$ \frac12 (\|u(t)\|_{L^2}^2)'=-\|\nabla u(t)\|^2_{L^2}\le -\lambda_1\|u(t)\|_{L^2}^2$$
and hence
$$ (\|u(t)\|_{L^2}^2)'+2\lambda_1\|u(t)\|_{L^2}^2\le0. $$
So
$$ (e^{2\lambda_1t}\|u(t)\|_{L^2}^2)'\le0 $$
Integrating this from 0 to $t$, one has
$$ \|u(t)\|_{L^2}^2\le e^{-2\lambda_1t}\|u(0)\|_{L^2}^2. $$
Now it is easy to see
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty}\|u(t)\|_{L^2}^2=0. $$